# printing event confirmations

Tags: civievent, printing

I'm in the process of trying to move people from paper to online, but we have to make a gentle transition and know that there are some important members who so not have email. We'd like to make the offline registration process as much like the email process as we can.

If its just one person booking by post and they do have an email, then there is an option to confirm by email and that works nicely.

If they don't have an email then it sensibly doesn't offer the email confirmation option. I can't see any way of sending a confirmation letter that includes the details of the event. If you use a PDF letter then it doesn't have any tokens for the event booking. I looked at using the Name Badges but they can't look like tickets (local politics) and that would mean a fiddle to get it out as one per page and there is no way of getting other text (like joining info) in.

I would also like something that recorded when people book multiple tickets (themselves and others) like with the online bookings but can't see any way to do that. But I will deal with that in a separate question as I have other issues with multiple bookings and there is enough in this one already.

I'm using CiviCRM 4.7.22 and WordPress 4.9

Answer (score 2):

I was going to say, "Do a search for participants (not contacts), then select PDF letter" ... but then I tried it - and there are still no event tokens.

Some work was done to add participant tokens in [CRM-16734](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16734).  Although the Fix Version is 4.7.15 the related PR ([PR-9038](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9038)) was closed without merging.

So unfortunately I don't have a solution for you but confirming this is a known gap in functionality. It would be great if you can do anything to help progress the issue.